# Derive the exact ODE solved by specific function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have been given the task to find the exact ODE which is solved by 
\begin{equation} y(x)=\pm\sqrt{K|x|-1} 
\end{equation}
I ended up with $y'=\pm  \frac{K}{2y}$, but I am not sure that this is correct. I was then given the task to derive this ODE and check whether my result was correct by inserting the original equation into the new ODE that I derived. I do not know what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\qquad & y^2 = K|x| - 1 \\
\implies &y^2 + 1 = K|x|\quad \left(\implies K > 0, |x| \geq \frac{1}{K}\right) \\
\implies &2yy' = K\operatorname{sgn}(x) \\
\implies &2yy' = K\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right) = (y^2+1) \frac{x}{|x|^2}\\
\implies &2xyy' = (y^2 + 1),\; \text{ given that } x \neq 0.
\end{align}
The above equation is the required ODE, with the necessary domain conditions.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. 
But, if $|x|\ge 1/K \Longrightarrow |x|\not=0 \Longrightarrow \frac{x}{|x|}=\pm 1$.
And that is how I got the ODE $2yy'=\pm K$. 
Now in any case, to get the next derivative, am I supposed to derive with respect to x? It just says "derive the ODE that is solved by $y(x)=\pm \sqrt{K|x|-1}$"

Comment: You can't just substitute $\frac{x}{|x|} = \pm 1$. Actually, $ \frac{x}{|x|} = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } x > 0 \\ -1 &\text{ if } x < 0 \end{cases}$. So actually the ODE you have got is $2yy' = \begin{cases} K &\text{ if } x > 0 \\ -K &\text{ if } x < 0 \end{cases}$ - note that this is not the same equation as $2yy' = \pm K $

Comment: Oh, so that's where I am wrong. But now that I am supposed to derive this new equation, should I derive with respect to x again? So that on the left side I get $\frac{d}{dx}2yy'=2(yy''+y'^2)$

Comment: You can differentiate it again - but note that then the equation formed will have more solutions than the one you started with - i.e. $y = \sqrt{K|x| - 1}$ will not be the only solution. Rather you can use substitution, i.e. substitute $|x| = \frac{y^2 + 1}{K}$.

Comment: Okay, I will try it out. Thank you very much for your time.